# counting the number of times a script is executed

Tags: php, mysql

I have got two php forms - question.php and marks.php. I want that each time question.php  submits its values to marks.php , the variable $total in the form marks.php be incremented. I have tried using static variable but still am not able to get it done!

Comment: So, you want to show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Ever thought about a for loop? for (i=1; i<=10; i++)

Comment: even of i increment it using a loop .. the incremented value does not persists across the two pages...

Answer (score 2):

Nothing "inside PHP" itself will persist anything across different page loads. You need to store the value somewhere "external", e.g.:

- write it to a file
- write it to a database
- store it in a memcache or other kind of cache
- send it to yourself in an email
- burn it into the screen of the computer and use an elaborate video camera and OCR setup to read it back
- ...
- maybe: sessions

Comment: I'd try "SESSIONS" before burning my screen, but it's just me.

Comment: @STT Well, sessions are user specific. Sounds like he wants a global count instead. But maybe sessions should be above screen burn in that list, I'll give you that... ;)

Comment: Indeed, you're right they're user specific, I didn't think that he wanted it as a global counter. Anyway I'd be open to try it somehow before permanently damage my hardware nevertheless :D

Comment: `while(Earth revolving around the Sun){ vote++; // for the fifth point }`

Comment: i think i wil give it a try using session variables